# TeamCity seems to be ignoring my service messages

Tags: teamcity

I'm using NUnit to run tests. I've made some of the tests emit TeamCity service messages, but TeamCity seems to be completely ignoring me:

```
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[progressStart 'Downloading {0}']", savePath);
...
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[progressFinish 'Downloading {0}']", savePath);
```

I've got this to work before, but it doesn't seem to want to work now. Is this because it's output from a unit test, or have I done something else wrong?

Comment: Do you see your messages written in the build output?

Comment: The messages are definitely there in the build log.

Comment: So it should be an encoding problem.